# Do the maximum launch capability figures of Falcon Heavy includes payload adaptor fairings or launch vehicle adaptors?

Tags: spacex, mars, launch, falcon-heavy

I would like to learn if stated payload capabilities of Falcon Heavy includes PAF. According to [Falcon User's Guide](https://www.spacex.com/media/falcon-users-guide-2021-09.pdf), SpaceX has two different PAF for Falcon 9. In the said document, smaller PAF doesn't have any rating for payloads heavier than 9-10 tonnes. So even if it is included, I am assuming it is the bigger (2624 mm) one.

I need this info because I need to make a mass budget for Martian mission. Do I use all the 16800 kg for payload, or I need to make room for launch vehicle adapter?

Comment: Might be worth looking at [NASA Launch Services Program Launch Vehicle Performance Website](https://elvperf.ksc.nasa.gov/Pages/Default.aspx) for more numbers. They give different payload attachment interface diameters and the payload masses given account for the adapters (i.e., don't worry about them). Note that you won't be able to send all 16,800 kg to Mars.